# Suitable lens for macro photography with Nikon D90

Tags: macro, macro-lenses

I own a Nikon D90 and use 18-105mm kit lens for my photography. I mostly shoot flowers and objects I can get close to. Some sample here:

http://yourshot.nationalgeographic.com/photos/8798926/
http://yourshot.nationalgeographic.com/photos/8689792/
http://yourshot.nationalgeographic.com/photos/4253842/

I would like to get much closer and capture minute details of flowers and other objects. But with 18-105mm lens I can't go any closer to objects as the lens won't focus. So can someone please suggest options for me? like what lens I need to opt for? or will extension tubes help?

I also have Nikon 50mm 2.8 lens which I use for portraits.

Thanks

Comment: What macro lens you get really depends on how much working distance you want/need.  You can also look at extension tubes (typically a cheaper option) https://www.amazon.com/Neewer-Focus-Extension-Cameras-NW-N-AF1-BL/dp/B015XQH6AM/

Comment: I use the 85mm f/3.5 macro and have been quite pleased with it. There are a lot of excellent condition used copies available as well.